# Run javascript on website without browser

Tags: javascript, linux, web, userscripts

I am using some Tapermonkey (Chrome) scripts that constantly run on website. They are executing every 120 seconds and interact with the website: parse text and click website buttons. 
Now I need to transfer this task to embedded platform on Linux with limited resources. How can I run these scripts on website without launching the browser, using just some lightweight application? Can I convert userscript into javascript (if this has any sence)? Is there any javascript engine that allow to load external page and execute the script on it?

Comment: node.js, v8 chrome engine,

Answer (score 0):

TRY this : http://jasmine.github.io/
U can test your javascript

other useful links are

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ 
needs browser, to run but its automation , will start browser itself

js unit tests
http://jsunit.berlios.de/products.html

Comment: Thanks for responce. I decided to use PhantomJS